# How to turn on night light only for a specific monitor in a dual-screen setup

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi, night-light

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.02. I have connected an old LG monitor via an HDMI cable. When I turn on the Night light- both the monitors (laptop screen and old LG monitor) are affected (as they should ideally).

Is there a way to only use the night light on the original screen(laptop) and view the old screen(LG) as it is without the night light?

Edit: I am using the "Join Display" feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I was also trying to do the same thing for my external monitor. Here is what I have done.

First open your terminal and list the connected devices using `xrandr` (if `xrandr` is not installed, then you might want to install it).

```
    xrandr -q | grep " connected"
```

Here you might see the list of connected devices as:

```
    HDMI-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 476mm x 267mm
    eDP-1-1 connected 1920x1080+0+1080 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 193mm
```

`HDMI-0` is my external monitor. I wanted to turn on night light in this monitor so I altered the value of RGB via `--gamma` flag as:

```
    xrandr --output HDMI-0 --gamma 1.1:0.8:0.7
```

You might also want to alter the brightness of the monitor. You can do that by via `--brightness` flag as:

```
    xrandr --output HDMI-0 --gamma 1.1:0.8:0.7 --brightness 0.55
```

Comment: any Idea how to revert these settings??

Comment: Usually changing the settings from default "Night light" feature overrides the earlier set settings. It is as simple as      
1) Pressing Super key (Windows in my keyboard/might be CMD for Mac user)
2)Typing display in the search box
3) Choosing the display option from Setting of OS(Ubuntu)
4) Select Night Light and switching between the on and off state of night light